# PHP header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found") return 200 instead of 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers, php-5.5

`header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")` does not seem to be working at all because I keep getting `'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200'` instead of `'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '404'`.

This is my php code where `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")` is when the mysql return 0 result.

```
$this->item = $this->Database->fetchRow($sql,array(
            ...
        ));

if($this->item === false)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "PHP continues.\n";
    include  WEBSITE_DOCROOT.'local/template/base/article/not_found.php';
    die();
    echo "Not after a die, however.\n";
}
```

.htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /projects/mywebsite/path/index.php
```

So if I type in the pages that cannot be found in the database,

```
http://website/path/foo/ --> 200 but should be 404
http://website/path/foo/boo/ --> 404 correct
http://website/path/foo/boo/too/ --> 404 correct
```

It seems that it is caused by `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Yes `/projects/mywebsite/path/index.php` be called for `/foo`. Also are you sure code is reaching to your `header` function? Did you see `PHP continues` on 404 page?

Comment: Yes I can see it. Also I can see a 404 return code in Firebug/HTTP Watch but I get `200` in `  `WEBSITE_DOCROOT.'local/template/base/article/not_found.php'` which is confusing!

Comment: oh ok got it, `REDIRECT_STATUS` is correctly set to 200 since your php code is being invoked by rewrite rule not by `ErrorDocument` line.

Comment: yes you are right! what can I do with the rewrite rules? I need that `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]` for pages that can be reached.

Comment: If you can figure out via SQL query that `/foo` is invalid `$_GET['url']` value then no need to rely on `REDIRECT_STATUS` at all

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you are trying to suggest....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65383/discussion-between-anubhava-and-tealou).